# How to make child elements bisects the width of their parent element

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I wrote a navigation bar like this:

```css
.site-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #09C;
  line-height: 52px;
}
.site-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.site-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">首页</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Now I need each `<li>` tag bisects the width of `ul` (it's parent). If the count of `<li>` is known, I can simply give an percentage to `<li>`, 
in this case:

```
.site-nav li {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

However, the `<li>` is dynamically generated ( I use [razor](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c)), so I don't know how many `<li>` will generated.

So is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: If you vote on answers, hoping to leave an explanation. So that we better understand where there are problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `flexbox`, and you can have it dynamic  because you are using property `flex-grow:1` in child `li` which will fill the remaining space available

> If all items have `flex-grow` set to `1`, the remaining space in the
>   container will be distributed equally to all children.

[Flexbox Tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.site-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #09C;
  line-height: 52px;
  display: flex
}
.site-nav li {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">首页</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: downvote for this?? care to explain?

Comment: looks good, why have an downvote? same as @Mateusz Woźniak 's

Comment: really don't know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `flexbox`. Check the snippet below.

```css
.site-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #09C;
  line-height: 52px;
  list-style: none;
}
.site-nav li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.site-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  2 columns:
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">首页</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  4 columns:
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">首页</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  8 columns:
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">首页</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">首页</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: so basically my answer but 3 minutes later? :)

Comment: there was nothing when I started :)

Comment: ya that happened to me before